# UNION ALL subquery with JOIN generating syntax error

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to data from 3 tables, then join that result set, as follows:

```
SELECT     r.region, 
           r.recordtype,
           i.entity,
           COUNT(i.requestid) AS responses 
FROM       ( 
                  SELECT region, 
                         recordtype,
                         entity, 
                         requestid 
                  FROM   ( 
                                SELECT region, 
                                       'a' AS recordtype,
                                       requestid 
                                FROM   db.table1 
                                UNION ALL 
                                SELECT region, 
                                       'b' AS recordtype,
                                       requestid 
                                FROM   db.table2
                                UNION ALL 
                                SELECT region, 
                                       'c' AS recordtype,
                                       requestid 
                                FROM   db.table3 
                         ) union_results
           ) r 
RIGHT JOIN db.responses i 
ON         r.requestid = i.requestid 
GROUP BY   r.recordtype, 
           r.region,
           i.entity
```

What I am ultimately looking for, is a result of rows where the i.requestid is in the result of the union of the other three tables then grouped as shown and while I am not even sure that I am using RIGHT JOIN correctly I am getting an error on the basic query.

requests table 1 (a)

```
requestid  region
abcdef  us
bcdefg  eu
cdefgh  eu
```

requests table 2 (b)

```
requestid  region
fghijk  eu
rstuwx  eu
jklmno  eu
```

requests table 3 (c)

```
requestid  region
klmnop  eu
ghijkl  eu
opqrst  eu
```

responses

```
requestid  entity
abcdef  1
rstuwx  3
ghijkl  5
opqrst  5
```

result

```
region  entity  recordtype  count(responses)
us  1  a  1
eu  3  b  1
eu  5  c  2
```

I'm successfully using the union on it's own as a subquery, but when paired with a join I get the following error so am looking for pointers on what I have done wrong I've got the blindness now. I'm using the intermediate table as the eventual plan is to create some dynamic columns here based on the expanded data (samples only represent some of the columns I will ultimate pull once the query works).

> FAILED: ParseException line 4:6 cannot recognize input near '('
> 'SELECT' 'region' in joinSource Command exiting with ret '64'

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have 3 such similar tables?

Comment: If you remove `db.responses` (`i`) from your query and all references to it, does it work?

Comment: I'd try `GROUP BY r.region, r.recordtype`, when the other problem is corrected.

Comment: Create a view for the UNION ALL part. JOIN it and GROUP BY.

Comment: @jarlh Not my schema but there is a lot of data across the tables so can understand splitting it for.

Comment: Don't see need for the intermediate SELECT aliased as r. JOIN the UNION as alias r to responses.

Comment: @LarsSkaug That would mean removing the JOIN though right?

Comment: @June7 Plan is to expand that as the query advances to do some conditionals on the aggregate data. Should still work though.

Comment: I did a quick test with UNION joined to responses with grouping and no error. Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables.

Comment: Check for TAB characters and replace with spaces

Comment: @June7 Added sample data and desired result. Thanks!

Comment: Field entity is not in the query so why would it be in the output dataset?

Comment: @June7 I added it to show that data from both the request and response tables are required in the final result given the table/query/results edit I made to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me:

```
SELECT r.region, r.recordtype, entity, Count(responses.requestid) AS responses FROM
(SELECT region, "a" AS recordtype, requestid FROM Table1
 UNION ALL SELECT region, "b", requestid FROM Table2
 UNION ALL SELECT region, "c", requestid FROM Table3) AS r
RIGHT JOIN responses ON r.requestid=responses.requestid
GROUP BY recordtype, region, entity;
```

Comment: Thanks - using the same query I still get the same error so it doesn't seem to be related to the intermediate query: `cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT' 'region' in joinSource`. I'm stumped.

Comment: Okay, I should mention I am using Access so must be something about HiveQL. Try bracketing all object names: `[region]`.

Comment: Same issue, sorry. I did select * on the outer and removed the group by too. I've been reading about how HiveQL doesn't support co-related subqueries, but I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: I cannot replicate issue so cannot offer solution.